# Using ArcGIS field calculator to find and replace words in string?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I obtained a KML file that has the popup information already formatted as HTML. I converted the file to a shapefile to use in AGO. Unfortunately the links that are supposed to operate a search function on a site do not work because the site reads the `%20` as characters and not a space. Here is a sample of the data in the PopupInfo field:

`<b>Chemicals in Inventory</b> \t<br> \t \t<a href="http://cameochemicals.noaa.gov/search/aloha?name=SULFURIC ACID;cas=7664-93-9">SULFURIC ACID</a> <br/>   \t \t<b>Fac. Emergency Coordinator 24-hour phones</b> \t<br> \t \t1-800-KNOWEHS (1-800-566-9347) <br/>  \t \t<b>Emergency Contact 24-hour phones</b> \t<br> \t \t(972) 839-6769 <br/> 1-800-KNOWEHS (1-800-566-9347) <br/>  <br/>  Last Modified:8/11/2016 <br/>`

I removed the %20 and replaced it with a space using the find and replace function, but the website still reads it as %20. My next guess was to just remove the name=(chemical name), but I don't know if there is a wildcard I can use to do them all at once or if I need to do them separately.

Is there a wildcard I can use in either VB or Python in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Comment: If I understand you correctly try this using field calculator with Python checked : YOURFIELD = !YOURFIELD!.replace("%20" , " ")

Comment: I used Find and Replace to replace the %20 and it appeared to work when I pasted a sample into Notepad. I reloaded the service and it still came up with the same error message:"Name contains DIESEL%20FUEL;cas=68476-34-6 matched 0 datasheets". What I wanted to try to do was remove the "name=DIESEL FUEL;" from the HTML:(snippet)aloha?name=DIESEL FUEL;cas=68476-34-6">DIESEL FUEL. Ed, I tried your suggestion and had the same results as with Find and Replace.

Comment: I think this is going to be your answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768070/transform-url-string-into-normal-string-in-python-20-to-space-etc  and https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/443058-url-special-character-replacements

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] your question to show what your data looks like, please?  Just type it in with no formatting, once it looks like it should, highlight the text and click the **`{}`** button.  Did the last comment by @ed.hank resolve your question?  If not, can you absorb more of precisely what you havce tried into your question body, please?